# "Знай только": какая часть речи и как употребляется на письме?

Tags: семантика, словосочетания, части-речи

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно употреблять словосочетание "знай только", то есть что оно значит, какое после него следует время, какое наклонение? И какая это вообще часть речи? Вот несколько примеров из "Нацкорпуса".

*Ну, скажи, зачем ему работать, раз он и так во всякую дыру пролезть может? **Знай только** хватай, что надо...  Ты бы лучше спал, Гек, все равно я с тобой больше разговаривать не буду.*
[А. П. Гайдар. Чук и Гек (1939)]

*Ему что!  **Знай только** ножами в передней стучит!                                                                              Так-с, так-с, так-с, я совершенно с вами согласен.*
[И. С. Тургенев. Холостяк (1849)]

*— Они **знай только** под венцом стоять, а свадьбу уладить наше дело.*
[М. Н. Загоскин. Русские в начале осьмнадцатого столетия (1848)]

Answer (score 2):

*Ну, скажи, зачем ему работать, раз он и так во всякую дыру пролезть может? **Знай только** хватай, что надо... Ты бы лучше спал, Гек, все равно я с тобой больше разговаривать не буду.* [А. П. Гайдар. Чук и Гек (1939)]

***Знай только*** — фразеологическое сочетание в значении **частицы**.  Используется как обычная частица (***знай*** можно убрать).

**[Знай себе](https://rus-phraseology-dict.slovaronline.com/4432-%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5)**

***Только*** — как вариант (вместо ***себе***)

**[Справочник по пунктуации](https://%20%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%92.%20%D0%9C.%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%92.%20%D0%92.%20%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%98.%20%D0%92.%20%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%90,%20%D0%91,%20%D0%92,%20%D0%93,%20%D0%94,%20%D0%95%20%D0%96,%20%D0%97,%20%D0%98,%20%D0%9A,%20%D0%9B,%20%D0%9C%20%D0%9D,%20%D0%9E,%20%D0%9F,%20%D0%A0%20%D0%A1,%20%D0%A2,%20%D0%A3,%20%D0%A4,%20%D0%A5,%20%D0%A7,%20%D0%A8,%20%D0%AD,%20%D0%AF%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%201.%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%202.%20%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%203.%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%20(%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5)%20%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%99%20(%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%91%D0%95),%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%20%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82:%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83!%20%D0%98.%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA.%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%82.%20%D0%91.%20%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD,%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85.%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE.%20%D0%90.%20%D0%B8%20%D0%91.%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5,%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.)**
В. М. Пахомов, В. В. Свинцов, И. В. Филатова

**ЗНАЙ (СЕБЕ), частица**

**Не требует** постановки знаков препинания.

Знай колет: всю испортил шкуру! И. Крылов, Крестьянин и работник. Перекрестился Агапий и **знай себе** дальше полощет. Б. Акунин, Пелагия и черный монах. Престарелая Матильда **знай себе** вязала, как ни в чём не бывало. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Град обреченный.